# React.js useState Hook takes a while to update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks, use-effect

When i load async data from an API and set the data to a state it takes a small amount of time while this data is accessible to the state and my code breaks.

What is the approach to wait for the data to load, do my checks and then decide to either update or skip updating? I have written a sample code to illustrate the situation.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Demo() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    const [existing, setExisting] = useState(false)

    function loadData() {
        return API.get("sdd", "/sdd")
      }

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()


        try {
            const data = await loadData();
            setUserData(data);
           
          } catch (e) {
            onError(e);
          }
          
      
          console.log(`userData`, userData)
          for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
            if (Object.values(userData[i])[3] === id) {
              setExisting(true)
            } 
          }
      
          ///check if existing is false and add the data else alert and skip
    }


    return (
        <form className="form1" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
            <button > Cancel</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you're checking `existing` where you have the comment *"check if existing is false and add the data else alert and skip"* then, yes, that will have the old value. State updates are asynchronous. `existing` won't have its new value until your component function is called again.

If you need to know what its value will be as of that comment, do this:

```
let existing = false;
console.log(`userData`, userData)
for (let i = 0; !existing && i < userData.length; i++) {
    if (Object.values(userData[i])[3] === id) {
        existing = true;
    } 
}
setExisting(existing);
// ...use `existing` (which is the local, not the state variable) here...
```

---

Side note: `async` functions return promises. If you use an `async` function as an event handler, nothing is going to use the promise that it returns. That means you need to be sure that the `async` function never rejects that promise, by wrapping **all** of it in a `try`/`catch`, not just part of it. (Or don't use `async` functions where the thing receiving their return value doesn't understand and handle promises.)

Comment: This worked. i have used your approach and also thank you for the side note. Will definitely have a look at it.  I had some additional errors in my code. maybe its time for a coffee break. Have a nice day ! :)

Comment: @Etika49 - LOL, I know what that's like! :-) Glad that helped. You too!